# How to interleave 2 string arrays into one string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

Given 2 string arrays of the same size, e.g.:

```
a = ["what's", " programming", " be"]
b = [" your", " question?", " specific."]
```

How would you interleave them into one string, i.e.:

```
"what's your programming question? be specific."
```

?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could use [`zip`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000260) to bring them together, [`flatten`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000280) to flatten out the extra arrays that `zip` adds, and [`join`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M000239) to get a simple string:

```
a.zip(b).flatten.join
```

And if you didn't have the convenient spaces in your arrays:

```
a = ["what's", "programming", "be"]
b = ["your", "question?", "specific."]
```

Then you could tweak the `join`:

```
a.zip(b).flatten.join(' ')
```

And if you weren't sure if the spaces were there or not, you could put them in with `join` (just to be sure) and then [`squeeze`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/String.html#M001202) out any duplicates:

```
a.zip(b).flatten.join(' ').squeeze(' ')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
p [a, b].transpose.inject(''){|s, (a, b)| s << a << b}
# => "what's your programming question? be specific."
```

**Added in response to Andrew's comment**

I have no objection against mu is too short's answer; I think it is pretty rubyish. But somehow, using `inject` or `each_with_object` is faster than going with `flatten` and `join`. Below is my benchmark.

```
a = ["what's", " programming", "be"]
b = [" your", " question?", " specific."]

$n = 1000000
Benchmark.bmbm do |br|
  br.report('flatten join'){$n.times{
    a.zip(b).flatten.join
  }}
  br.report('inject'){$n.times{
    [a, b].transpose.inject(''){|s, (a, b)| s << a << b}
  }}
  br.report('each_with_object'){$n.times{
    [a, b].transpose.each_with_object(''){|(a, b), s| s << a << b}
  }}
end
```

*Result* (ruby 1.9.2 on ubuntu linux 11.04)

```
Rehearsal ----------------------------------------------------
flatten join       2.770000   0.000000   2.770000 (  2.760427)
inject             2.190000   0.000000   2.190000 (  2.195147)
each_with_object   2.160000   0.000000   2.160000 (  2.158263)
------------------------------------------- total: 7.120000sec

                       user     system      total        real
flatten join       2.810000   0.010000   2.820000 (  2.838118)
inject             2.190000   0.000000   2.190000 (  2.197567)
each_with_object   2.150000   0.000000   2.150000 (  2.148922)
```

Comment: @Andrew I actually tested, but it seems slightly faster than using `flatten` and `join`.

Comment: @sawa: Interesting. Did you try `each_with_object`?

Comment: @Andrew I just tried it. `each_with_object` is still faster than `flatten` and `join` but slightly slower than `inject`. I think I am testing right. Can you also try?

Comment: @sawa: Sorry, my morning (Oz time) Stack Overflow binge has been big enough as it is. But it may be worth asking a seperate question on why `each_with_object` is slower than `inject`.

Comment: @Andrew I will try that. In the meanwhile, I will add my benchmark.

Comment: @Andrew Actually, the difference between `each_with_object` and `inject` was subtle in this case, and even went the other way around in my another run of benchmark.